# Как инициализировать структуру Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>>

Tags: c#

Kак правильно инициализировать:

```
Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как обычно:

```
// создаем саму очередь
Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> queue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>>();  
// создаем ключ и значение для KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>
int key = 10;
byte[] value = new byte[4] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
// добавляем в конец очереди KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> с указанным ключом и значением
queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(key, value));
```